# BDD Feature Files guidelines

Tags: bdd

I'm sure every story cannot be considered as a feature and a feature can be mapped to multiple stories. Sometimes big stories are split into multiple stories for easy reference.

Are there any guidelines/references while creating features? i.e what all can be considered as a feature?

User login can be considered as a feature where multiple positive and negative scenarios can be grouped under it. (i.e valid credentials, invalid credentials, license etc)

But when it comes to page navigation (or) loading a page (say after funds transfer, user navigates back to the home screen) - can this be a feature?

Answer (score 2):

BDD is about communication and effective information.
Scenarios and feature files are meant to gather this information in a readable way.

A good scenario has a title that shows the intent of action and the steps that explain what are the conditions to be able to perform the action (*Given*), the action itself (*When*), and the consequences of the action (*Then*).

A feature file constitutes a set of related actions, that would make answer one's questions about a certain area of the application.

> User login can be considered as a feature where multiple positive and
>   negative scenarios can be grouped under it.

True. If someone wants to understand the conditions to *login*, you read the *login* feature file.

> page navigation (or) loading a page

These are **not** user actions. You would not pitch you software by saying it enables the user to load a page.

> after funds transfer, user navigates back to the home screen

Here you have a user action: **Fund transferring**.

On the *Fund Transferring* feature file, you will have all the actions related to fund transferring. If someone wants to understand how fund transferring happens on your system, he/she should read this file.

> every story cannot be considered as a feature

True. One user story may start the implementation of the *Fund Transferring* features in the app, but other may **change** or **complement** this first story. It should trigger **changes** and **appends** on the *Fund Transferring* feature file. It should be a [living document](https://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/living-documentation), showing the current understanding of the feature.

Comment: Nicely explained.

Comment: @João Farias, page loading itself may not be a action but when user clicks on a button - he/she may be redirected to a different page. Isn't it an action? Also, once the page, we expect certain elements to be displayed. How do you validate/suggest these cases in BDD?  Even in the funds transfer case which I pointed, user will not be directly navigate back to home page after transfer - user has to certain (may be click back button) to go back..